# Read client's info. behind Nginx proxy server

Tags: asp.net, nginx, asp.net-core, proxy

I'm using Nginx as a proxy server in front of an asp.net core application. In my application, I want to read the client request header, specifically the IP and the User-Agent, but I'm getting the Nginx Info instead. I'm using this configuration:

```
server {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.18.2.3:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The application gets the IP Address using this line:

```
var remoteIpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Any idea what could be the problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `nginx` will not change `User-Agent` - it just passes it through the proxy (you do not need to redefine it). What `nginx` info are you getting? `nginx` is not a user agent - so it is not clear why your application thinks that it is.

Comment: The application is receiving the request with the nginx IP address and a Debian OS that the nginx on. The request is sent from a Windows machine. @RichardSmith

Comment: With any proxy, the application will receive the request from the IP of the last proxy in the chain. The application needs to ignore that IP address and use the `X-Forwarded-For` header to deduce the client's IP address. You will not be able to fix the application by changing the proxy.